# Rate limit exceeded for target Task-List-EvaluateTaskAttributes

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I'm using Twilio API via twilio-ruby gem to list TaskRouter tasks with  `evaluate_task_attributes`. Sometimes I get

Twilio::REST::RestError
[HTTP 429] 20429 : Unable to fetch page
Rate limit exceeded for target Task-List-EvaluateTaskAttributes
https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20429

I'd like to know what exactly limits Twilio sets.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Typically the Twilio API restricts each account to 100 concurrent connections to the API and will throw 429 errors for further connections.

It is best to try to limit your connections to less than 100, but also to implement retries for 429 errors with an exponential backoff. This [article on dealing with 429 Twilio errors](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044308153-Twilio-API-response-Error-429-Too-Many-Requests-) has some further suggestions.

Comment: I had a comment from twilio yesterday, and they replied that they changed those limits recently, it's 1 request per second.

Comment: In that case you should reduce your calls so that you make less than 1 per second and implement retries and back offs to make sure you can recover from that.